# How to find all urls in an HTML text with regex?

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, search

I have the source code of a webpage held in a textbox, i would like to search the textbox and place all the links that are from that sites own domain (www.test.com) into a string list.

Example:

The textbox has the following links buried within the source code

```
a href="index.html
a href="www.test.com/about_us.html
a href="mailto:test@test.com
a href="www.google.com/partners.html
```

and i want to extract the index.html and about_us.html and place them into a string list.

Ive tried:

```
    For Each i As Match In Regex.Matches(TextBox2.Text, "\b" + url + "\b")
        list1.Add(i.Value)
    Next
```

but cant seem to get it to work, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the source code (or at least a small part) held in the textbox please?

Comment: Whats in the textbox is the source code of any random webpage, i'm collecting analytics from them. but one of the first from the list is this one view-source:http://www.streatley.co.uk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using Stephan's answer and got the code i needed from [regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

```
        Dim strRegex As String = "<?href\s*=\s*[""'].+?[""'][^>]*?"
        Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None)
        For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(TextBox1.Text)
            If myMatch.Success Then
                ' Add your code here
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
<a.+?href\s*=\s*(["'])(?<href>.+?)\1[^>]*>
```

with the `IgnoreCase` flag.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mU2nU2/4)

Comment: Thank you so much that is an amazing site and a wonderful explanation but how would i expand group 1 to include any page name so basicly anything.html or random.php ect without writing them all in manually?  sorry about making you do all the work but i really have no idea with regular expression.

Comment: @crackruckles Please check my update with the generic version.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Pattern As String = "href=" & """" & "(w{3}.\w+.\w{3})"
        Dim MyString As New Collection
        Dim regex As New Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
        For Each match In regex.Matches(TextBox1.Text)
            MyString.Add(match.Groups(1).ToString)

        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Preconditions:

You have the following:

1. A form named Form1
2. A Button Named Button1
3. A TextBox Naled TextBox1

VB will insert those names by default when you create these objects.

The `private sub` will handle the button clicking event and it will store the matches in a string collection.

You can add the following code to echo in a msgbox

```
For Each member in MyString
Msgbox(Member)
Next
```